# Sequelize - custom date query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a query like this:

```
  const users = await User.find({
    updated_at: {
      [Op.lte]: moment.utc(date).toDate(),
    }
  });
```

What I would like to have is logic like this: find User which has updated_at date + 10 days later then today's date `moment.utc(date).toDate()`. Above query misses + 10 days part. It checks if updated_at is later then today's date. I need updated_at + 10 days there instead. Is it possible inside sequelize query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my computer at the moment but try this, i'll try something similar when i get back

```
[Op.lte]: new Date(new Date(updated_at).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

otherwise you could use a raw query to do that date math in your database call... or you could simply add another column that stores update_at + 10 days if you are using it constantly....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add` function provided by `moment`. I tried it as follows -

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone')
var date = moment.utc("2019-02-12T18:00:00+01:00").add(10, 'days').toDate()
console.log(date);
```

I get following result on my console -

```
2019-02-22T17:00:00.000Z
```

So your Sequelize statement should be as follows -

```
 const users = await User.find({
    updated_at: {
      [Op.lte]: moment.utc(date).add(10, 'days').toDate(),
    }
  });
```

I hope it helps!